# Why does "noncommutative probability" capture quantum probability?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, quantum-mechanics

In [this article](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/245a-notes-5-free-probability/#more-3466), Terry Tao states that non-commutative probability can be used for quantum probability. However, he then goes on to explain non-commutative probability without explaining how it relates to quantum probability. **So why does non-commutative probability help us to model quantum probability?**

Comment: Are these not synonymous?

Comment: "Need" is a strong claim, and it's not what Tao says. It's a useful framework but you don't need it. I give some details here: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/08/18/noncommutative-probability/, https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/finite-noncommutative-probability-the-born-rule-and-wave-function-collapse/